# error: not valid array Param

Tags: future, pyomo

I want to use pyomo.environ import * and have this code:

```
## Define sets ##
model.i = Set(initialize=i_set)
model.p = Set(initialize=j_set)

## Define parameters ##
model.precedence = Param (model.i, initialize=precedence, doc='precedence relationship')
model.duration = Param (model.p,initialize=duration,doc='duration')


## Define variables ##
model.x = Var(model.i, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.z = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
```

but i gives me this error:

```
 ERROR: Constructing component 'duration' from data=None failed:
    KeyError: "Error setting parameter value: Index '42' is not valid for array Param 'duration'"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\0.- MS CM UH\3.- Data Analysis in CM\hwk#7\Exercise 9.5.py", line 33, in <module>
    model.duration = Param(model.p,initialize=duration,doc='duration')
```

I've already define the parameter Param. I don't know why i have this error.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition for the `duration` initializer?  How about the `j_set`?  The error is almost certainly because the `duration` object (a `dict`?) has a key (`42`) that is not in the `j_set` used to initialize `model.p`